# Is there anyway to collaborate on a Google Document in realtime using VIM?

Tags: macos, vim, google-chrome-extension, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to use the VIM keyboard commands to edit a Google Document.  Preferably I'd like to use my .vimrc file and have changes I make reflected in real time (or at least on save).  I want to do this for a technical coding interview.

So far I've tried using GoogleCL which only pushes/receives changes on quitting VIM (which is too slow). And I've tried the Vimium Chrome plugin but that seems to be just for navigation not text editing.  I however may be overlooking a feature of one of these.

I'm using OSX and Chrome, Safari or Firefox.

Comment: What are you really trying to do. Do you expect someone else to see your edits in real time - or actually collaborate/jointly edit?

Comment: Best case scenario would be collaborate/jointly edit, but I'd settle for just seeing my edits, as long as I could see theres in a separate instance or something.  This is for a technical interview where you have to code in a shared Google document.

Comment: If you want to impress in your interview, you create your own app to extend the editing capabilities of Google Docs... see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs for a pointer on where to start. Unlikely to be the optimal solution though. I would have thought desktop sharing would be far preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- sync your google docs then edit normally
- use [vim-anywhere](https://github.com/cknadler/vim-anywhere) plugin
- use GoogleCL inside `au FileWrite`
- use some library to quickly create your own thing, for instance [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) (see short example on its page).

To collaborate and see changes real time you could for instance use ruby library to upload/dowload changes every now and then. If you always overwrite your original file even as you edit it, you can diff external changes to see what the other users did.